# Pygame freezes after initial click event

Tags: python, pygame

I want to alternate between X's and O's in my tic-tac-toe game. The only problem is that after the initial click which places an O it freezes. It doesn't continue further. I expected that the while loop 'continue' from off the if statement but it's like it doesn't register any more events. Also, I used an alternator which seems to be fine, I'm reasoning that the collation of events restarts but that should just register it??

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygame
import sys
import pygame
import os
from PIL import Image

pygame.font.init()

size = 320, 240
black = 0, 0, 0
white = 255,255,255
red = 255, 0, 0

x1y1 = [(100, 0), (100, 300)]
x2y2 = [(200, 0), (200, 300)]
x3y3 = [(0, 100), (300, 100)]
x4y4 = [(0, 200), (300, 200)]

ser = []
for a in range(0,3): 
        for b in range(0,3):
            ser.append((a,b))             

def centroid(coord1, coord2): 
    xx = 50
    yy = 50
    coords = []
    for a in range(0,3): 
        for b in range(0,3):
            if a  == int(coord1) and b  == int(coord2):
                coords += tuple([xx + a*100, yy + b*100])
                return tuple(coords)

def fourCorners(a,b,length,width): 
    center = (a, b)
    corner3 = (int(a + length/2), int(b + width/2))
    corner2 = (int(a + length/2), int(b - width/2))
    corner4 = (int(a - length/2), int(b + width/2))
    corner1 = (int(a - length/2), int(b - width/2))
    return [corner1 ,corner2 ,corner3 ,corner4]

def withinRect(a,b,corners):
    if len(corners) != 4: 
        print('Pass a list parameter of length 4.')
    elif int(corners[0][0]) >= int(a) >= int(corners[1][0]) and int(corners[0][1]) >= int(b) >= int(corners[1][1]): 
        return True    


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300))

screen.fill(white)
pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 128), x1y1[0], x1y1[1], 3)
pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 128), x2y2[0], x2y2[1], 3)
pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 128), x3y3[0], x3y3[1], 3)
pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 128), x4y4[0], x4y4[1], 3)

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\E-books\\Coding\\Projects')
os.path.abspath("X.png")
ximg = pygame.image.load("X.png")
ximg = pygame.transform.scale(ximg, (80,80))

os.path.abspath("O.png")
oimg = pygame.image.load("O.png")
oimg = pygame.transform.scale(oimg, (80,80))


def insert_x():
    global result 
    result = ()

    def alternate(): 
        while True:
            yield 0 
            yield 1


    alternator = alternate()    
    next(alternator)
    button = pygame.Rect(0,0,300,300)
    while True:
        ev = pygame.event.get()
        for event in ev:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()      
                x, y = event.pos
                evb = pygame.Rect(x,y,10,10)
                for val in ser:
                    va = tuple([100*x + 10 for x in val])
                    if (va[0] + 100 >= x >= va[0] and va[1] + 100 >= y >= va[1]):
                        result += va
                if (button.colliderect(evb)):
                    if next(alternator) == 1:
                        screen.blit(oimg,[result[0], result[1]])
                        next(alternator)
                        pygame.display.flip()
                        result = ()
                        continue
                    elif next(alternator) == 0:   
                        screen.blit(ximg,[result[0], result[1]])
                        next(alternator)
                        pygame.display.flip()
                        result = ()
                        continue
                    pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        continue

insert_x()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the construct

> ```
> if next(alternator) == 1:
>       # [...]
> elif next(alternator) == 0:
>       # [...]
> ```

`alternator` is evaluated in the `if` statement the 1st time. If it doesn't `yield 1` but `yield 0`, then the condition is not fulfilled and the `elif` statement is evaluated. But in the `elif` statement `alternator` is evaluate a second time and now it `yield 1` in any case. 
This cause that the `elif` condition is never fulfilled. The application seems to hang, because in this state neither the `if` condition nor the `elif` condition will be fulfilled at any time.

Evaluate `alternate` once, before the `if`-`elif` statement, to solve the issue:

```py
a = next(alternator)
if a == 1:
    screen.blit(oimg,[result[0], result[1]])
    result = ()
elif a == 0:   
    screen.blit(ximg,[result[0], result[1]])
    result = ()
```

By the way, the `continue` statement and the `pygame.display.flip()` calls in the event loop are superfluous. The event loop will terminate when the message queue is empty and the single `pygame.display.flip()` call at the end of the main llop is sufficient.

Comment: Yes! It's cause it was being called everytime I stated it.